# Why we need Odoo Runbot?

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, gitlab, odoo, devops

My question is related to Runbot.

- `Why we need runbot of Odoo?`
- Once I'm choosing Stack as a Gitlab CI/CD with Kubernetes Integration then still I need to add runbot for testing purposes or tracking purposes or are there any alternatives of it?

Answer (score 0):

I've used 2 or 3 other CI environments including TravisCI as a replacement for Runbot. Runbot has some Odoo focused features to it, but in terms of CI workflows you can use something else pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

My reason for using runbot is like if we are doing certain customization and something else stops working. Sometime this situation comes. Then i do the same process in runbot to check the core functionality as Runbot is vanilla odoo, hence I can Identify if that's the expected behavior or something is wrong.